# unexpected results in array of pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, char

I wrote simple code but I've got unexpected result. my code is as below:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
const int MAX = 4;

int main () {
const char *names[MAX] = { "Zara Ali", "Hina Ali", "Nuha Ali", "Sara Ali" };

   for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
      cout << "Value of names[" << i << "] = ";
      cout << *(names + i) << endl;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

the result is as below:

```
Value of names[0] = Zara Ali
Value of names[1] = Hina Ali
Value of names[2] = Nuha Ali
Value of names[3] = Sara Ali
```

but i expect to get as :

```
Value of names[0] = Z
Value of names[1] = H
Value of names[2] = N
Value of names[3] = S
```

could you guide me to what is happening there ?

Comment: _Why_ did you expect this result?

Comment: Can you explain why you expect this code to only print the first character of each string?

Comment: because i think a pointer point to first element of array.

Comment: @FarshadGholami What?

Comment: @melpomene   i have an array which in any element of that i have an address to an array of char. so i think any those addresses point to the first element of array of chars.

Comment: @FarshadGholami That's correct, but `cout << ptr_to_char` doesn't just print the char the pointer is pointing to; it also prints the following chars in memory.

Comment: @melpomene thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The meaning of `*(names+i)` is exactly the same as `names[i]`, that's why. See, for example, [this](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr.sub#1) online C++ standard draft defining this equality:

> **5.2.1 Subscripting**
>
> (1) ... The expression E1[E2] is identical (by definition) to
>   *((E1)+(E2))

If you expect to print the first character of each string, you'd have to write `**(names+i)` or `*(names[i])` or `names[i][0]`.

Comment: well I thought for example "zara  ali" is an array of characters. Therefore I expected that names[0] stores the address of first character of the mentioned string.

Comment: `names[0]` actually points to the first character of the respective string; yet it has type `const char*`, and when passing a variable of type `const char*` to operator `cout::<<`, then this pointer is interpreted as a string (i.e. a sequence of characters terminated by a string end character `\0`), and not as a single character. That's how `cout::<<` is overloaded for this specific type.